# Is there a ratio test for multivariate power series?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find out where a multivariate power series of the form

$\sum_{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_m \in \mathbb{N}}c_{\alpha_1} \cdots c_{\alpha_m}z_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots z_m^{\alpha_m}$

converges. I know that the Cauchy-Hadamard-Theorem can be applied here, however it would be more practical to work with a multivariate version of the ratio test. Does this exist, and if it does, where can I find out more about it?

Also, I have a (probably dumb) question about notation in the Cauchy-Hadamard-Theorem.

Wikipedia says,

> Let $\alpha$ be a multi-index (a ''n''-tuple of integers) with
>   $|\alpha|=\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n$, then $f(x)$ converges with radius
>   of convergence $\rho$ (which is also a multi-index) if and only if
>
> $\lim_{|\alpha|\to\infty} \sqrt[|\alpha|]{|c_\alpha|\rho^\alpha}=1$

How exactly is $|c_\alpha|\rho^\alpha$ defined?

Is it $|c_{\alpha_1}+\cdots+c_{\alpha_m}| \cdot (\rho^{\alpha_1} \cdots \rho^{\alpha_m})$?

Comment: It looks like $c_\alpha$ is a number, not a multi-index: the coefficient of the power series is $c_{\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_m}$, not $c_{\alpha_1} \cdots c_{\alpha_m}$.

Comment: Thanks, I misread that. This makes more sense